# How do I extract an integer value from a HTML?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to extract a **value 50** from `span` using jquery.

Below is HTML:

```
<span class='WebRupee'>Rs</span>50
```

Comment: only this much html you have or you have some more after `50` and before `<span class='WebRupee'>`?

Comment: Since a downVoter obviously disapproves of all solutions offered - by downvoting all - perhaps he/she would have the guts to explain why these solutions are so crappy? or have the integrity to say - these are all wrong because ... and here is a better alternative....   
     
Simply downvoting without reasoning or providing an alternative is bollocks and whomever does this - should be reminded that this site promotes a best practise approach - if my answer is wrong - fair enough - downvote it - but have the balls to own that and to say why you disagree with the solution I have provided

Answer (score 1):

The 50 isn't present inside the `span`.
If the placement of the amount is fixed, you can use `$(...).contents()` method on the parent node of the span to extract the text nodes.

A better solution would be to use the following DOM structure.

```
<span class='WebRupee'>Rs</span>
<span class="amount">50</span>
```

and then extract the value using `$('.amount').html()`.

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to change your DOM structure as @mjzeus said.

Or else u can use the `contents()` function and use a filter for text only (nodeType3). In this case it will return Rs50, since Rs is also text. If you really need this method to extract the data you can filter out the Rs.

```
$('.parentOfWebRupee').contents().filter(function() {
      var result = this.nodeType === 3;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a data attribute and set the value of the data-value in its own span

```
<span class='WebRupee' data-value="50">Rs</span>
<span class='WebRupeeValue'></span>

//js(note the parseInt in case you need to do calculations on the value)

var value = parseInt($('.WebRupee').data('value));
$('.WebRupeeValue').text(value));
```

Comment: Since a downVoter has obviously disapproved of all solutions offered - by downvoting all of us - perhaps he / she would have the guts to explain why all these solutions are so crappy? or perhaps have the integrity to say - these are all wrong because ... and here is a better alternative....

Comment: Simply downvoting without reasoning or providing an alternative is bollocks and whomever does this - should be reminded that this site promotes a best practise approach - if my answer is wrong - fair enough - down vote it - but have the balls to own that and to say why you disagree with the solution I have provided

Comment: Exactly, he/she might be having solution for this unexplained question. We all have tried our best to provide the solution, but downvoting without any reason itself shows unprofessionalism.

Answer (score 1):

@Mohan: It is quite easy to extract the text outside of the span tag. Check the given working code. Hopefully, you will be able to sort out your issue using this.

Kindly follow these steps to implement it:

1. Include the latest version of jQuery in the header part.
2. Enclose you above mentioned code in p tag with class of your own choice (I have taken wrapper class in my example)
3. Before closing body tag put the jQuery code as given in the example.

Working Code using jQuery 2.1.1:

```js
var rate = $("p.wrapper") //can not use div as will target all the divs
    .clone()    //clone the element so that it will not effect current HTML output
    .children() //select all the children
    .remove()   //remove all the children
    .end()  //again go back to selected element
    .text();
    

alert(rate);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="wrapper">
  <span class='WebRupee'>Rs</span>50
</p>
```